# $this->getStoreCategories() is Not returning anything after deleted data from the categories releated tables in magento

Tags: magento, navigation, categories

I need help with the navigation menu. The navigation menu is not showing any categories when I added new categories in admin panel. No Categories showing in the navigation menu at all.

Here is what I did to the database that caused the problem. 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_datetime`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_decimal`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_int`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_text`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_varchar`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;

insert into `catalog_category_entity`(`entity_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_set_id`,`parent_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`path`,`position`,`level`,`children_count`) values (1,3,0,0,’0000-00-00 00:00:00’,’2009-02-20 00:25:34’,’1’,1,0,1),(2,3,3,0,’2009-02-20 00:25:34’,’2009-02-20 00:25:34’,’1/2’,1,1,0); 
insert into `catalog_category_entity_int`(`value_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) values (1,3,32,0,2,1),(2,3,32,1,2,1); 
insert into `catalog_category_entity_varchar`(`value_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) values (1,3,31,0,1,’Root Catalog’),(2,3,33,0,1,’root-catalog’),(3,3,31,0,2,’Default Category’),(4,3,39,0,2,’PRODUCTS’),(5,3,33,0,2,’default-category’);

After I ran the above queries, all the categories in the navi menu are gone, and no categories showing even I add more categories in the admin panel.

I checked the top.phtml file, the code $this->getStoreCategories() is Not returning anything.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to update the index?

Comment: Why on earth were you doing this at the DB level? Models exist for a reason.

Comment: have you added your default category to your store?
and have you checked all your category has "Show in menu" option to "Yes"? please check it in admin and reindex once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by inserting the data back by running the Magento sample data sql file.